# PayPal as Payment Processor for RAILS Marketplace App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, stripe-connect

I have a Ruby on Rails webapp that is using Stripe Connect to manage payments through buyers and sellers and I take a 6% commission. I understand PayPal Adaptive Payments would be the route to go if I want to incorporate PayPal however they have now added a notice to the API.

```
> Adaptive Payments moving to limited release
>     
>         Important: Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should
> not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal.
>     
>     https://devblog.paypal.com/adaptive-payments-limited-release/
>     
>      Our end goal with this project is to migrate all existing users of Adaptive Payments on to the modern products that will be the core
> of our future development APIs, namely Braintree v.zero and the PayPal
> REST APIs.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to set up the same functionality as Stripe Connect for a marketplace using PayPal? I believe Braintree doesn't incorporate PayPal to their marketplace functionality. Is there someway I can develop the chained payments using PayPal REST API? Any direction would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you got any solution for the above?

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma I ended up using paypal adaptive payments api successfully. I can share the implementation if you're still interested.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has an [adaptive payments SDK](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby) for Ruby and if you look at an [issue search in activemerchant](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20paypal%20adaptive%20payment), you'll see some people discussing projects that have added support for adaptive payments.